# Какой алгоритм использовать, чтобы высчитать оптимальное количество задержки перед повторным обращением для API?

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм

**Ситуация**: Есть API, на него обращается ПО "исполнителей" для получения задания. Есть проблема: заказов не всегда есть в таком количестве, чтобы "занять" всех исполнителей. Есть желание избежать запросов каждую секунду, и самостоятельно ориентировать исполнителей через сколько секунд попытаться обратиться ещё раз.

**Вопрос**: какой алгоритм для вычисления этого времени?

Алгоритм может быть неидеальным("коллеги" корректируют сейчас вручную), но желательно как можно близким к реальности.

**Данные в распоряжении:**

1. Количество исполнителей в системе.
2. Количество задач.

Думаю, придётся вводить поле "last_execution" чтобы высчитывать "активных" исполнителей за N время.

**Нагрузка на БД по запросам**

Количество исполнителей будет примерно ~15 000. Каждое обращение генерирует:

- 1 SELECT-EXIST запрос
- 1 SELECT-запрос с LEFT JOIN

**Другие детали**

- Никаких статистических данных, к сожалению, сейчас нет. Есть просто эмпирические данные коллег. Но в процессе работы можно будет скорректировать.
- Приложение на PHP 7.2. База данных MySQL. Я ищу алгоритм, ограничен языком PHP, но думаю что основная логика исполнения будет лежать на базе данных.

UPD:
**Примечание**: Увы, установлено правило, что на стороне "клиентского ПО" нельзя ничего изменить. Данное "ПО" готово ориентироваться только на параметр "retry_after" с кол-вом секунд когда повторить.

UPD #2:
*"Простым языком"/Примером*: Сегодня по заказам "негусто", штук 100 в час появилось. А 6000 исполнителей онлайн каждую секунду шлют запрос на проверку задач. А вчера было "погуще", 2000 заказов/час.

Как видим: нельзя установить какую-то одну задержку и "жить спокойно". Надо её регулярно(начнём хотя бы раз в день) обновлять.

А цель: оптимизация. Зачем серверу получать тысячи запросов в секунду, если заказов пока мало? Вот этот вопрос пытаюсь решить...

Comment: Возможно ли узнать, сколько времени уйдет у конкретного исполнителя на конкретную задачу заранее? Ну и вы можете сделать этакий long-poll на сервере. Пусть исполнители встают в очередь, посылая всего один запрос, а вы им отправите ответ, когда очередь до них дойдет.

Comment: @EzikBro, Спасибо за ответ. К сожалению, неизвестно сколько времени заберет у исполнителя. Важная поправка: установлено правило - в клиентском ПО ничего нельзя изменить, он будет ориентироватьсят только на параметр "retry_after". 
Поэтому, сейчас задача состоит в том, чтобы грамотнее этот параметр высчитывать

Comment: Вы вполне можете реализовать механизм ограничения запросов через middleware, используя [HTTP 429](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) для ответа, вычисляя и передавая в Retry-After период пере-опроса. Для алгоритма вычисления периода можно использовать что-то из популярных методов определения среднего взвешенного значения. Что именно и как зависит от вашего конкретного требования к определению приоритетности пользователя - то ВАМ нужно будет составить что-то базовое, и потом это дорабатывать.